# Detect edges of the screen UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have an `UIView` **animation** to move an object on the screen and I want the **animation to be stopped** (and the object to keep the position when the animation is stopped) when the object goes off the screen.

I want my object to always be visible, and to **stop moving** when it meets an edge of the screen. The target point may be anywhere.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
self.MyObject.center = targetPoint;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I tried to fire a scheduled timer which check if the object is off screen but it seems that the position my object does not change.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I may not have understood your question clearly. But from what i have understood, if you just want to move the object out of the screen, why cant you just animate the object till it disappears from the screen by setting the object frame to be more than the screen size?

Comment: Actually, I want my object to always be visible, and to stop moving when it meets an edge of the screen.

Comment: u can calculate it yourself its very easy logic man. just check the new calculated position in off the screen bound if so stop Ur timer used to animate.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code sample if you are looking to animate the object from left to right edge of the screen.

```
CGRect objectFrame = self.MyObject.frame;
objectFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width-objectFrame.size.width;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[self.MyObject setFrame:objectFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers.